# run "lookup" against multiple hosts in ansible

Tags: templates, ansible, lookup, prompt

Ansible playbook only run against one host

```
root@osboxes:~/ansible_project/second_p# cat conditionals_3.yml 
---
- name: show hostname
  hosts: ios-devices
  connection: local

  tasks:
     - name: show hostname
       ios_command:
               commands: "show run | in hostname"

       register: output

     - debug:
        var: output

     - name: pause with render
       pause:
        prompt: "{{lookup('template', 'conditional.j2')}}"
root@osboxes:~/ansible_project/second_p# cat conditional.j2 
output = {{output}}

{% if "las-a" in output.stdout[0]%}
I am "las-a"
{%else%}
I am "las-b"
{%endif%}
root@osboxes:~/ansible_project/second_p# cat hosts
# Ansile hosts file for lab
[all:vars]
ansible_user=xxx
ansible_ssh_pass=xxx
[ios-devices]
las-a
las-b
```

The actual output is

TASK [pasuse with render] *************************************************************************************
[pasuse with render]
output = {'failed': False, u'changed': False, u'stdout_lines': [[u'hostname las-a', u'logging origin-id hostname']], u'stdout': [u'hostname las-a\nlogging origin-id hostname']}

I am "las-a"
:
ok: [las-a]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************
las-a              : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
las-b              : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

But I want I am "las-a" and I am "las-b"

Comment: Lookups do only happen on the ansible host if I recall that correctly. That might be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pause_module.html#pause-pause-playbook-execution) "`Pauses playbook execution ...`" i.e. whoever reaches it first pauses all forks.

Try debug and you'll see both "las-a" and "las-b".

```
- name: "Debug (was: pause with render)"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'conditional.j2') }}"
```

---

**How *pause* works** (ansible 2.7.9)

Test with inventory

```
test_jails:
  hosts:
    test_01:
    test_02:
    test_03:
```

Playbook below with **`run_once: yes`**

```
- hosts: test_jails
  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "Please enter the value"
        echo: yes
      register: result
      run_once: yes
    - debug:
        var: result.user_input
```

gives

```
PLAY [test_jails] ***************************************************************************

TASK [pause] ********************************************************************************
[pause]
Please enter the value:
[[ok: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_02] => {
    "result.user_input": "TEST"
}
ok: [test_01] => {
    "result.user_input": "TEST"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "result.user_input": "TEST"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_02                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_03                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

But the same playbook with **`run_once: no`** gives

```
PLAY [test_jails] ***************************************************************************

TASK [pause] ********************************************************************************
[pause]
Please enter the value:
[[ok: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => {
    "result.user_input": "TEST"
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "result.user_input": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "result.user_input": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_02                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_03                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

- Note `ok=2` in test_01 PLAY RECAP. In both cases, *pause* executed only once.
- Without `run_once: yes` the registered variable was not available to other hosts.

Comment: I tried your code, and it displays both. I don't know how to ack multiple prompts from a terminal? one by one? my original code has issue? or it is just impossible to do so?

Comment: It's impossible. *pause* will run only once per playbook.

Comment: 1:echo: yes here is to display the input when I input it after "Please enter the value: " otherwise it is "output is hidden" . Am I right?   2: The 'run_once' parameter is designed to run a specific play in a playbook once PER PLAYBOOK, even if there are multiple hosts referenced in the playbook . But why    run_once: yes can keep the play running in 3 hosts(test_01 02 03)? confused